# How to disable storybook's keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, storybook

I am using storybook 6.0.25 for one of my vue project's documentation in which I am switching between records with less than and greater than buttons of keyboard.
But when I press less than, storybook responds to the keyup with it's own shortcut to open 'About' page.
Is there any way to make storybook stop implementing its all or specified shortcuts?
Other shortcut keys are 's', 'd', 'f' which can be obviously used by developers for different purposes!
Below is the main.js config file in my vue project for storybook:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../../src/**/*.stories.@(js|ts)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-controls'
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // Use Sass loader for vuetify components
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
          vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
          'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',          
        },
      },
    });
    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can turn on or off shortcuts by setting `enableShortcuts:true/false`. More information can be found [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/features-and-behavior).

Comment: Yeah I saw 'what' to do, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out 'where' to write this change of config with vuejs. I tried editing in vue.config and config of storybook, but it won't make any difference!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I got it.
After clearing localStorage of browser, in my 'preview.js' file, I had to add following to change the configs

```
import { addons } from '@storybook/addons';

addons.setConfig({
  enableShortcuts: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other workaround I found is adding following part in preview.js file but it is again deprecated to above solution in v7 of storybook(as suggested in console by storybook):

```
import { addParameters } from '@storybook/vue';
addParameters({
  options: {
    enableShortcuts: false
  }
});
```